# How do I use the same Wistia video multiple times?

Tags: jquery, html, video, wistia

I've been able to embed a wistia video on to a page of mine, but now I'm confused about how I could use multiple instances of the same video.

Like, for example, if I wanted to have a second version of the video that doesn't autoplay like video1 has been assigned to do below.

```
window._wq = window._wq || [];
_wq.push({ "hashedidhere": function(video) {
  video1 = Wistia.api("hashedidhere");
  video1.play();
}});
```

Can anyone give me some insight?

**edit:** To further illustrate my question, I want to do something like this...

```
window._wq = window._wq || [];
_wq.push({ "hashedidhere": function(video) {
video1 = Wistia.api("hashedidhere");
video2 = Wistia.api("thesamehashedidhere");
video1.play();
video2.someotherfunction();
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question! You can pull that off without writing any JS, but instead by including the `autoPlay=true` embed option in the class name of the video container:

```html
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_te2r1m8yjn autoPlay=true" style="height:360px;width:640px"></div>
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_te2r1m8yjn" style="height:360px;width:640px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response- please see my edit in the question I provided.

Comment: Hm, the problem is that since you can only refer to the video by its hashedId, and you want to have two instances of a single video (with a single hashedId) on the same page, there would be no way to distinguish between `video1` and `video2` there. They'd be defined as the exact same thing. As a work around, you could make a new copy of the video in your account, so you could have the same video content with two separate hashedIds: http://wistia.com/doc/media#moving_and_copying_media & http://wistia.com/doc/data-api#medias_copy